# Data always show [object object] why?

Tags: javascript, sql, codeigniter

I've some problem with my query. i'm using datatables and codeigniter on this practice.
i want to count the data, and ordering by postedby but the data i've been count always show [object object].

```
public function ajax_list_peneliti_perpostingan()
{

    $list = $this->post->get_datatables_peneliti_perpostingan();
    $data = array();
    $no = $_POST['start'];
    foreach ($list as $post) {
        $no++;

        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT count(postedby) FROM peneliti where postedby = "'.$post->postedby.'"'); 
        $row_count = $this->post->count_postedby($post->postedby); 

        $row = array();
        $row[] = $post->postedby;
        $row[] = $row_count['0'];

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $output = array(
        "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
        "recordsTotal" => $this->post->count_all_peneliti_perpostingan(),
        "recordsFiltered" => $this->post->count_filtered_peneliti_perpostingan(),
        "data" => $data,
    );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

is my console result

```
{"draw":"2","recordsTotal":481,"recordsFiltered":481,"data":[["administrator",{"postedby":"administrator","Total":"1"}],["fadil",{"postedby":"fadil","Total":"25"}],["",{"postedby":"","Total":"1"}],["tilan",{"postedby":"tilan","Total":"160"}],["Editor",{"postedby":"Editor","Total":"2"}],["budi",{"postedby":"budi","Total":"1"}],["admin",{"postedby":"admin","Total":"291"}]]}
```

Comment: Are you using `alert()` or concatenating something with object? Use `console.log(obj)` to debug.

Comment: Your actual result would occur if you are trying to output the ACTUAL result on your HTML element / alert message. If you are trying to debug your result, you should extract the object:

`alert(result.draw)`

Comment: Show us script as well

Answer (score 0):

I think ,the problem is

```
$row = array();
        $row[] = $post->postedby;
        $row[] = $row_count['0'];

        $data[] = $row;
```

you can change to

```
 $data[] = array(
                 'postedby'=>$post->postedby,
                 'total'   =>count()
                    );
```